# Load a variable from PHP file using jQuery Ajax load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Assuming my example.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
$variable = "I am a variable";
?>
```

and on another page I have:

```
<div id="loadme"></div>
```

How can I get that variable to my div?

Can it be achieved by using `.load()`?

I can imagine could be something like this:

```
$('#loadme').load("example.php", $variable);
```

Am I even close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, you need to echo the variable in the PHP file -

```
<?php
$variable = "foo";
echo $variable;
?>
```

Then load like this -

```
$('#loadme').load('example.php');
```

The content of `#loadme` will now be 'foo'.

EDIT: Based on the OP's comments -

Each echo containing a variable could be a div with an id, e.g.,

```
echo '<div id="foo">$variable</div>';
```

Then your load statement would look like this -

```
$('#loadme').load('example.php #foo');
```

Now #loadme would contain the variable echoed in that div. This is not an efficient plan if the variables are to be re-used by JavaScript/jQuery code.

Comment: This makes sense, but in the php file I'm using I echo many other things, I didn't know this was important so I didn't mention it before. Is there another approach to get just one variable from many in the php file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are close I think. Just a simple change

```
<?php 
    $variable = "I am a variable";
    echo $variable;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can request your example page with AJAX like that:

```
<?php
// exemple.php

json_encode(array(
  'my_var' => 'my_value'
));

?>

<!-- something.html -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'exemple.php',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data)) {
      alert(data.my_var);
    }
  })
</script>
```